# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 207 Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Soy algo nuevo con laravel y me ha surguido un problema y no logro resolverlo. Ya he visto la documentación oficial al igual que algunas otras preguntas aquí mismo pero no logro resolverlo.

Lo que quiero lograr es un update a la base de datos, pero al no tener éxito estoy intentando simplemente mandar un response con algun mensaje que tampoco logro que funcione.
Lo estoy intentando por medio de ajax, quiero mandar información al controlador y alli que se realice el update, en este caso que responda un simple mensaje...

Esta es mi ruta:

```
Route::patch('pdv/inventario-transferencia/{store}/{idTran}/update', 'InventoryController@editQtTemp');
```

Este es mi coigo que se ejecuta al presionar un boton:

```
$('.btn-qtyTemp').click(function(e) {
    //ADAN
    e.preventDefault();
    id_el = $(this).data('id');
    valInput = document.getElementById('input-'+id_el).value;      
    el = id_el.replace("quantityTemp-", "");
    var  valueIdTran = parseInt(el);
    if(!isNaN(valueIdTran)) {

         $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-XSRF-Token': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'patch',
            url: location.pathname + '/' + el + '/update',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                isValInput: valInput
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
                console.log('entrando');
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('Todo Correcto'+data.isId);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('Algo anda mal'+data.isId);
            }
        });
    }
    //      alert('id_el: '+id_el+' el: '+el+' value: '+valueIdTran+' val: '+valInput);
});
```

Y esta es la funcion del controlador:

```
public function editQtTemp(Request $request, $store, $idTran) {


       if ($request->ajax()) {

            $this->validate($request, [
                'isValInput' => 'required'
            ]);

            //
            $isValInput = $request->input('isValInput');

            if ($isValInput=='') {
                # code...
                return response()->json([
                    'isId' => ['Valor Invalido']
                ], 422);
            }
            else {
                return response()->json([
                    'isId' => [$isValInput]
                ], 200);
            }
        }
}
```

El error que me aparece es el siguiente:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 207:


    in RouteCollection.php line 207
    at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 194
    at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 142
    at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 729
    at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 652
    at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 628
    at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 214
    at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 43
    at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 36
    at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 55
    at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 61
    at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 36
    at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 40
    at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
    at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 100
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 115
    at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 84
    at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 52
```

No tengo idea de que pueda estar sucediendo, he realizado esto en PHP puro pero con laravel estoy teniendo muchos problemas... Gracias

Comment: Has verificado que la url que esta generando por el " location.pathname + '/' + el + '/update', " es el correcto?

Comment: Si la he verificado y si es la correcta, incluso he puesto la url real y no me funciona

Comment: Sigue apareciendo el mismo error agregando el _method..., no logro entender que sucede... Ya que practicamente tengo otros metodos muy parecidos y si funcionan correctamente

Comment: Y si pruebas corriendo el siguiente comando: php artisan route:clear

Answer (score 0):

En tu ajax prueba incluir el _method: "PATCH" de este modo

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'PATCH',
            url: location.pathname + '/' + el + '/update',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                isValInput: valInput, _method: "PATCH"
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
                console.log('entrando');
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('Todo Correcto'+data.isId);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('Algo anda mal'+data.isId);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido, inenta enviar tu petición `ajax` de la siguiente forma:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            headers: {
               'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            url: location.pathname + '/' + el + '/update',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                isValInput: valInput,
                _method: 'PATCH'
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
                console.log('entrando');
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('Todo Correcto'+data.isId);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('Algo anda mal'+data.isId);
            }
        });
```

Actualmente si usas formularios, de acuerdo al [estándar HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-form-method) sólo son aceptadas tres tipos de peticiones `post`, `get` y `dialog`, para ejecutar alguna otra acción en Laravel, lo que debes de incluir es un parámetro con el nombre `_method` y asignándole el nombre del método que quieres utilizar diferente a `post` (`patch`, `put`, etc...), el valor de `method` se queda como `post`, de lo contrario, Laravel no reconocerá el tipo de acción al que quieres acceder.

En `ajax` si es válido usar los nombres de los otros métodos como tal, a menos que estés desarrollando para navegadores de la prehistoria o del IE 6 para abajo, no funcionarían, pero los navegadores actuales si lo soportan. También es válido enviar el parámetro `_method` como mencioné anteriormente.

Comment: Eso es verdad solamente si el formulario es enviado a través de un submit normal. En ajax es totalmente válido enviar un method: 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'PATCH' sin necesidad de enviar el data _method que pones.

Comment: @memoadian Sí, claro, por eso puse que si llegaba a usar formularios con ese tipo de petición.